# Find the shaded areas A1, A2, A3

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, parametric

[image]

I think i know how to find the angles KAG and KAH

that's what i did: (this is the picture from my assignment sheet)

[image]

then i have to find the shades areas A1,A2 and A3 but i don't know how to start it.

Comment: Is the cut-out a quarter circle?

Comment: no, i don't think so..but i am not sure..

Comment: OK, well you'll need to make some kind of assumption about that curve to determine its length, and the width (height) as a function of the position along it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the dotted lines in your first diagram is marked "$R=2$" I think we can assume the cutout is supposed to be a quarter circle (but perhaps you should check with your instructor).

Imagine sticking a piece of paper onto the curved surface.  If you use a bit of imagination I think you should be able to see that it will be possible to take the paper and flatten it out (with no tearing or wrinkling) and that it will be a rectangle.  So the area is just the area of a rectangle: the height is given and the width will be the length of a quarter circle (why? - see the original diagram) with radius $2$.  I think you should be able to find $A_1$ from this - try it.

Hint for $A_2$: divide the shape into two simpler shapes and add their areas.

Hint for $A_3$: similar to $A_1$, but harder (a bit) because the vertical sides are of different lengths.

Good luck!